# Kotlin Coroutines concurrency problem with Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two coroutines that run in parallel. One is a producer who changes the global state and sends an event to everyone in the `SharedFlow`, and the other is a consumer who must receive the state. If the state already exists, then just print it, and if not, then subscribe to the `SharedFlow` and collect the state in the future through a `collect` method.

I discovered that my code is not thread-safe because in the line where the comment may occur the case that in parallel on this moment the new state will be emitted and will not be able to receive new state. So we missing the new state because we have't subscribed on flow yet. Please tell me how I can change the code so that the code becomes thread safe and we could get the new state by the flow without replacing `MutableSharedFlow` with channel? Thank you very much!

Here is the code:

```kotlin
val mutableFlow: MutableSharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow()
val flow: Flow<String> = mutableFlow
@Volatile 
var state: String = ""

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val consumerDelay = 2_000L
    val producerDelay = 2_001L // emit state in 1 ms longer

    launch {
        delay(consumerDelay)

        if (state.isNotEmpty()) {
            println("The state has been updated...")
            showState(state)
        } else {
            println("State hasn't been set yet, waiting... :(")

            /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            * HERE IS THE MOMENT WHEN PRODUCER MAY EMIT EVENT
            * BUT WE HAVE NOT SUBSCRIBED YET AND WILL NOT RECEIVE IT
            * IN THE FUTURE
            * */

            launch {
                flow.collect { newState ->
                    showState(newState)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    launch {
        delay(producerDelay)

        val newState = "New State"
        state = newState // update the state variable
        mutableFlow.emit(newState) // notify all subscribers
    }
}

private fun showState(newState: String) {
    println("New state is: $newState")
}
```

Moreover, it seems that wrapping code of the consumer and producer in `mutex.withLock` will not help because  we asynchronously launch new coroutine inside consumer for collecting state with `flow.collect`

Comment: Why do you use the `state` variable in the first place? Flows/observable streams were invented specifically to replace patterns like above, where we check a variable in regular intervals. I think a correct solution is by removing that part entirely.

Comment: Generally, you make assumptions that are incorrect in concurrent world. Just because you delayed 2001ms vs 2000ms doesn't mean you control the order of execution. Even if the difference would be 1s then technically speaking, we still don't know the order of execution. In practice, it would be probably as expected, however, if you use 1ms of difference then the order is pretty much random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't use an external state storage to duplicate a flow.
To achieve this goal you have to use StateFlow instead of Flow.

Your code rewritten with state flow:

```
val mutableFlow = MutableStateFlow("")
val flow: StateFlow<String> = mutableFlow

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val consumerDelay = 2_000L
    val producerDelay = 2_001L // emit state in 1 ms longer

    launch {
        delay(consumerDelay)

        flow.collect { state ->
            showState(state)
        }
    }

    launch {
        delay(producerDelay)
        mutableFlow.emit("New State")
    }
}

private fun showState(newState: String) {
    println("New state is: $newState")
}
```